# Project reference - Type or namespace name 'Library' does not exist in the namespace; target framework matches (Asp.net)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, reference, frameworks

I have a project that references several other Projects in the solution. Project.Web references Project.Library; this reference has existed forever, but some changes have been made to Project.Library and now I'm getting the error "The type or namespace name 'Library' does not exist in the namespace 'Project' (are you missing an assembly reference?)"

I checked the target framework of all of my projects- Project.Web, Project.Library, RedirectModule, and SitecoreEloquaConnector - all of them are set to Target Framework = .NET Framework 4.5.2

I tried deleting the reference and readding it but I still get the error.

Comment: if all the projects are in a single solution, question..do they all share the same namespace? are there some classes that do not use namespace? can you show your code in regards to the namespace for those .. can you show the .cs file of the one where you are getting the error vs the ones that work..?

Answer (score -2):

You should remove the references and add them manually.When you click add reference,choose browse and look for the library dll.After that rebuild solution,and it should work.